# python server to manage wervices

Tags: python, web-services

i'm looking for a framework to build a webserver. This server will be used to manage webservices. huge amount of client may be able to connect to principally set data which will populate a noSQL DB. we work with python and naturally we would like a python framework. i looked at bottle, gevent, twisted and tornado but it's hard to choose.

Some feedbacks or propositions ?

Comment: Can you give more specific criteria for selection? This question, as it stands, is a very vague non-constructive shopping recommendation request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) And [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) are a good fit for this kind of situation, they don't assume anything about your data, so you can use whatever database you want.

[Here's how](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/others/#gunicorn) you can use them together.

Comment: i don't understand for example what are differences with twisted which is a network framework

Comment: Twisted is a bit lower level than flask, it deals with network connections, while Flask is more focused on writing web apps (and services), also check out [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) if you want something similar to twisted.